# Reusing code but with custom content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I have a bunch of pages with code for a nice looking footer area for buttons and stuff at the bottom of the page:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <footer>
                <a class="btn btn-warning actionButton" href="#/">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white" />
                    Cancel
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-primary actionButton" data-ng-click="saveSampleForm(sampleForm)" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-white" />
                    Save
                </a>
                <div class="version">v{{applicationdata.Version}}</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I know about the nginclude tag, but is there a way to reuse the `nav` portion of this code, but have custom `<footer>` content?  The buttons change from page to page.  Maybe a directive?  Still learning this stuff...
Edit: I know I could add the code for the `<footer>` content to my $scope and then use `{{footerContent}}`, but I would prefer to keep html out of my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly do so.  Here's an idea using transclusion with directives.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('navFooter', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'nav.html',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'E'
  }
})
```

**nav.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <footer ng-transclude>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Usage**

```
<nav-footer>
  <a class="btn btn-warning actionButton" href="#/">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icon-white"></i>
      Cancel
  </a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary actionButton" data-ng-click="saveSampleForm(sampleForm)" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-white"></i>
      Save
  </a>
  <div class="version">v{{applicationdata.Version}}</div>
</nav-footer>
```

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/iTysbI4EVI6Crrs69XMv?p=preview).

Comment: Actually- follow up question.  `nav-footer` shows as unable to resolve in my page... no biggie, but is there a way to get this to be happy?

Comment: You meant the sample link I sent doesn't work? http://plnkr.co/edit/iTysbI4EVI6Crrs69XMv?p=preview? It renders fine on my end. What's the error message?

Comment: The message is `Cannot resolve tag nav-footer`.  This is in VS2012.  Everything works just fine, but this warning pops up.  No biggie, just thought I would ask.

Comment: Lol, that's another story altogether. VS2012 apparently doesn't like tags it doesn't understand. Either see if you can configure VS.NET, or change the directive to be attribute directive, see this update for example: http://plnkr.co/edit/NkZ5JXsRKASPNPDzI4AT?p=preview. Same behavior, just minor tweak to keep original tag.

Comment: Close enough!  Using restrict 'A' and this `<nav data-nav-footer>` takes care of the warning, and works.  Cheers.